# Will my database be present in the jar file after building in java swing?

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing

I'm working on an application of download manager. The thing is I need to add proxy settings. I want to save the proxy settings entered by the user in a database using MySQL so that, when the user next opens the application he can find them saved. So, when I finish building the application, will the jar file contain the database? i.e Can the application run on any other computer without NetBeans or any other IDE without any problems? How should I implement the database to achieve this? My present database code is

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proxyInfo", "root", "root");
String sql = "select * from Proxy";
pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Are you asking how a you can have a different database connection string in a distributed application?

Comment: If I create an application including a database using MySQL and build it's jar file, will the jar file run on any other computer without any problems? Or will there be any problem like missing database?

Comment: *"..will the jar file contain the database?"*  Even if it does, the data will be read only.  So it will not be possible to.. *"..save the proxy settings entered by the user.."*  For saving the data, it will be necessary to install the DB onto the local file system.  Of course for simple name+value pairs, where both can be expressed as a string, there are many options for serializing them that do not require a DB.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I need to use the database. I'm restricted to save the settings in a text file and later retrieve them. Can you please tell me how to install the DB onto the local file system?

Comment: *"Can you please tell me how to install the DB onto the local file system?"*  That's too broad a topic for an SO answer, let alone a comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm unable to find any tutorials so that I can learn from. Can you please suggest one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are connecting to a mysql installation here:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proxyInfo", "root", "root"
```

That's mysql running on localhost, with a database called proxyInfo and the credentials root/root.

If you distribute your code this will not be available on any machine other than your own, unless that machine has a mysql installation running on the same port, with the same database, and the same credentials.

You have two broad choices.

You can instruct the user to provide the application with a connection string to a mysql installation they have available and run a database "script" that creates all the necessary schema.

If you are using hibernate or JPA, this schema might be auto-generated from your entity classes.  Otherwise you'll have to do it using jdbc, something like what's done here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-database.htm

Your other choice is to use an embedded database like http://hsqldb.org/  or https://db.apache.org/derby/.  With these you can include a database in your application and use any of the above methods to generate your database schema.

People do both. Embedded databases often only implement a portion of the my sql standard and you'll lose any mysql specific features you are depending on.